# Offset not working for VETS4212 data API

Tags: labor

Both the following URL API calls return the same record despite using the Offset filter:

https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json/limit/1/date_column/EndingPeriod/start_date/2015-07-01/end_date/2015-07-01/orderby/asc

https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json/limit/1/date_column/EndingPeriod/start_date/2015-07-01/end_date/2015-07-01/orderby/asc/Offset/2

Am I querying correctly?

Comment: And probably both are "Invalid API key"? This site [is not](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/editing-a-tags-name-wondering-about-us-gov-involvement-just-the-usual) a DOL service desk. Try to [report bug](https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/DOLAPI/issues) on Github. Probably your issue is related to [this one](https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/DOLAPI/issues/15).

Comment: No, I have a valid key and I get results back.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you, it seems that DOL blocks API requests from Russia or from Tor nodes.

Comment: @StanislavKralin interesting...is this recent?

Comment: @albert, yes. Perhaps I'm missing something, but the response to all my requests is 403 Forbidden "Invalid API key". I have obtained an API key about a week ago at developer.dol.gov. I'm not sure that the reason of the error is my location, but some US government sites really block foreign visitors, as far as I remember.

Comment: really odd/interesting. can you share a call you are making so we can compare? i'm making them and not getting these errors.

Comment: @albert, I'm just adding "X-API-KEY: e57b9016-431d-4b79-9712-1905d8a77fe8" header to the requests in the question (this is my real API key, feel free to use it). I'm getting connection timeout both from home and office, and I'm getting "403 Forbidden" when using Tor.

Comment: wonder if asking on their github would help...?

Comment: @albert, is this API key working for you? If yes, then DOL blocks both Russians and Tor. Anyway, it looks quite reasonable to block Russians, some Russian government sites blocks foreign IPs too. If no, then registration seems to be broken, or I missing something.

Comment: @StanislavKralin i think its your key. lets move this to a gist https://gist.github.com/jalbertbowden/eeba28a96f0aa7db245880482ca5fd4d

Comment: @Jeff What specifically are you expecting to return?

Answer (score 1):

I see that the O is capitalized in offset. so try this and it should work.

`curl -H "X-API-KEY: MYKEY" https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json/limit/1/offset/30/date_column/EndingPeriod/start_date/2015-07-01/end_date/2015-07-01/orderby/asc
[
    {
        "ReportID": "1956243",
        "ReportType": "4212",
        "FilingCycle": "2015",
        "EndingPeriod": "2015-07-01",
        "FormType": "Single Establishment",
        "OrgType": "Prime Contractor",
        "CoName": "Stealth Software Technologies Inc",
        "CoAddress": "12100 Wilshire Blvd",
        "CoCity": "Los Angeles",
        "CoCounty": "Los Angeles",
        "CoState": "CA",
        "CoZip": "90025",
        "HlName": "",
        "HlAddress": "",
        "HlCity": "",
      .... truncated
    }
]%`

`curl -H "X-API-KEY: MYKEY" https://data.dol.gov/get/vets4212dataset/format/json/limit/1/offset/20/date_column/EndingPeriod/start_date/2015-07-01/end_date/2015-07-01/orderby/asc
[
    {
        "ReportID": "1954920",
        "ReportType": "4212",
        "FilingCycle": "2015",
        "EndingPeriod": "2015-07-01",
        "FormType": "Single Establishment",
        "OrgType": "Prime Contractor",
        "CoName": "Impact Research and Technology LLC",
        "CoAddress": "3510 E Desert Broom Way ",
        "CoCity": "Phoenix",
        "CoCounty": "Maricopa",
        "CoState": "AZ",
        "CoZip": "85044",
        "HlName": "",
        "HlAddress": "",
        .... truncated 
    }
]%`

Comment: Should the ReportID's all be different. Or rather what's the unique key?

Comment: Really, what I'm trying to do is download all records for a starting period. how do I do that.

Comment: The current API has a limitation that would allow you to get about 200 records max .. so you would have to programmatically get the data by changing the offset and keeping the limit set to 200.

Comment: Great, thanks! Might want to update the docs here because 'Offset' is used instead of 'offset'.